# Django alter model data before rendering ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to generate an object that allows values to be stored in a standard unit, but displayed in different units based on the settings for the project. Below is an example where I need to be able to store the temperature of a room. I want the database value to be in Kelvin for ease of calulations, but want the users to be able to view/enter in F or C as the project requires.

The model can take the values from a form and convert them to Kelvin on save. I know this can be done in the form, but I have it here for other data entry methods. A striped down version of the model is as follows:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=255)            
    temperature         = models.FloatField(default=293.15)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.temperature = convert.temperature(self.temperature, 
            from_unit=self.plant.temperature_scale)
        super(Room, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I created a ModelForm to use in CreateView and UpdateView. I needed the ModelForm to limit the queryset for other fields (which works fine). Here I was able to convert the temperature field to the desired units for a new object in CreateView, but I can not seem to find the way to pull this off for an existing record

```
class RoomForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, plant, *args, **kwargs):
        super (RoomForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        self.fields['temperature'].initial = convert.temperature(
            value=self.fields['temperature'].initial, 
            from_unit='K',
            to_unit=self.fields['unit'].queryset[0].plant.temperature_scale)

        self.instance.temperature = convert.temperature(
            value=self.instance.temperature, 
            from_unit='K',
            to_unit=self.fields['unit'].queryset[0].plant.temperature_scale)

    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ['name', 'temperature']
```

For good measure, here are the views that call this form.

```
class NewRoom(CreateView):
    model = Room
    form_class = RoomForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super(NewRoom, self).get_form_kwargs(**kwargs)
        form_kwargs["plant"] = Plant.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['plant'])
        return form_kwargs    

class EditRoom(UpdateView):
    model = Room
    form_class = RoomForm
    template_name_suffix = "_update_form"

    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super(EditRoom, self).get_form_kwargs(**kwargs)
        form_kwargs["plant"] = Plant.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['plant'])
        return form_kwargs
```

In the templates (not forms) I use this to display the temperature correctly.

```
{{ room.temperature|convert_temperature:room.plant.temperature_scale }}
```

I assume I need to supplement the part where the ModelForm imports the data from the database record, but I could not identify where this happens in the django.forms source code.

I tried calling this manually in the shell

```
>>> from rooms.models import *
>>> from rooms.forms import *
>>> room = Room.objects.first()
>>> form = RoomForm(room.plant, instance=room)
>>> form.instance.temperature
20.0 
>>> form.as_p()
```

and the rendered form is as follows with the incorrect value for temperature

```
<p>
    <label for="id_name">Name:
    </label> 
    <input id="id_name" maxlength="255" name="name" type="text" value="Testing" 
        required />
</p>\n
<p>
    <label for="id_temperature">Temperature:
    </label> 
    <input id="id_temperature" name="temperature" 
        step="any" type="number" value="293.15" required /> 
</p>\n
```

I'm using Django version 1.10.3 if it's possible this is a bug.

Comment: Hi Brian, Did you write convert.temperature yourself, or is there any ready-to-use package I'm missing? I'd like to stick to conventions is there are any :)

Comment: I wrote my own convert module. I've seen a bunch of references to Pint, but I found the syntax confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While lucasnadalutti let me in the right spot, it did not manage to do the trick. Overriding the instance passed to the `ModelForm.__init__` and calling it again after altering.

```
class RoomForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, plant, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RoomForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        self.instance.temperature = convert.temperature(
            value=self.instance.temperature,
            from_unit='K', to_unit=self.fields['unit'].queryset[0].plant.temperature_scale)

        # Override instance passed to __init__ and call super again
        kwargs['instance'] = self.instance
        super(RoomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ['name', 'temperature']
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify data in your existing record before rendering, just do it in `self.instance` after calling the parent's `__init__`.

```
def __init__(self, plant, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RoomForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.instance.temperature = # ...
```

Comment: commented out my current `self.fields['temperature'].initial = ` and added `self.instance.temperature = ` to the end of `__init__`  and did not appear to do the trick. (Having both versions in there keeps me at where i was)

Comment: Putting a debugging statement in my code to print the value out in the terminal shows the right answer, but it doesn't show as desired on the page (even after restarting the server). adding `print(self.instance)` does print the name of the room in the  terminal.